# Track modifications of an object

Tags: oop

I am thinking about a general mechanism to keep track of changes of any members of an object. The idea is basically to save a timestamp to some member `lastModified` whenever a `set` is called.

My idea so far was to have some parent class (pseudo code here)

```
class Tracker {
    time lastModified;
    void onChildSet() {
        lastModified = NOW();
    }
}
```

and to inherit from this for my particular object

```
public class Object extends Tracker {
    sometype member;
    void setMember(sometype value) {
        member = value;
        onChildSet();
    }
}
```

What I don't like about this approach is, that I don't see how I could avoid the neccessity of the explicit call of `onChildSet()` from the parent class. Actually I am looking for some way to have `lastModified` updated automatically without having to write any code. Is there some concept how to achieve this?

Comment: what language would you like to implement this in, Java?

Comment: Might be a good place to use a proxy that you construct dynamically.

Comment: @hackattack: Unfortunately, this is somehow open ;). I'd love a solution which is available in some more languages, not only Java.

Comment: @PaulPhillips: I have to admit that I did not come accross the proxy pattern in OO so far. So many thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most dynamic languages have some way of intercepting method calls. For example all ruby objects have a method "method_missing" which gets called any time a method is invoked on an object that is not defined. You can use this feature to set up a proxy object to track a lastModified value. Another dynamic language, Actionscript 3.0 has a [Proxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html) Class in the API. Again, you can use this Proxy Class to intercept function calls. Unfortunately using proxies like this means you must modify how you define your methods. In the ruby case, method_missing is obviously only called when the method does not exists. What this means is that you have to define your methods on an object that is then wrapped by the proxy class. Look at the example I have put together in AS3. For a properity to be tracked it must be defined through the trackSet method, we can not define the method directly on the MyObject class. trackSet stores the name of the property in an object as well as a callback function. when setProperty is called on the proxy class the name of the properity is checked against the setters object and if exists lastModified is updated for that property and that properties callback is invoked.

```
package {

    import flash.utils.Proxy;
    import flash.utils.flash_proxy;

    public dynamic class Tracker extends Proxy {

        private var setters : Object;

        public function Tracker() { 
            setters = { };
        }

        public function getLastModified(name : String) : Number {
            return setters[name] ? setters[name].lastModified : 0;  
        }

        protected function trackSet(name : String, fn : Function) : void {
            setters[name] = {
                lastModified: 0,
                setter: fn
            };
        }

        override flash_proxy function setProperty(name : *, value : *) : void {
            if(!setters[name]) return;
            setters[name].lastModified = new Date().time;
            setters[name].setter(value);
        }

    }
}
```

-

```
package {

    public dynamic class MyObject extends Tracker {

        public function MyObject() {
            trackSet('member', setMember);
        }

        private function setMember(val : String) : void {
            trace('set member =', val);
        }

    }
}
```

-

```
var obj : MyObject = new MyObject();
obj.member = 'monkey';
trace('member getlast modified at', obj.getLastModified('member'));
```

Comment: Many thanks for your very detailed answer and the full code example!

Answer (score 1):

use InvocationHandler. you can also do the same on your own with bytecode instrumentation but InvocationHandler is simpler

Comment: Sounds like a great suggestion for Java - I will consider this. Thanks!

Comment: i forgot about another one: AOP